# Parsing pdf for image with iOS sdk for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cgpdfdocument, pdf-parsing

I am developing an app which contains pdf book reading. I found how to display pdf file page by page through CGPDF API. What I need to know is, can we somehow parse the pdf and find if a page contains certain image and if we can enable tap/ touch action on that image or on the page? What exactly I want to do is, if a page contains an image saying "Note", tapping on it opens another view with associated note. Any idea how it can be accomplished? Or any alternative solution? Sorry if the question is quite naive. Thanks